Converted VS-Code package to Unmanaged package
I just retrieved few components from an org via VS code for a fully functioning standalone CRM Analytics project. I was wondering if there are any tools or ways to convert this retrieved package () directly into an unmanaged package?
The retrieved package looks like this structure (this is not the actual package).


Converting to an unmanaged package is as simple as editing the package.xml file, adding the following line of code:
<fullName>DesiredPackageName</fullName>

This line should be placed on the third line of the package.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>DesiredPackageName</fullName>
    ...

When you deploy this to an org, this will cause a package (here, DesiredPackageName) to be created/updated with the components in the deployment.
Note that this is not an "installed" package. To install this package, first deploy your package to a development org, then use the "upload" function to package the code for installation in other orgs.
Also, you might want to look at Unlocked Packages instead. Unlike unmanaged packages, Unlocked Packages include the ability to upgrade the metadata later.

IMHO, anyone starting out on packaging should avoid creating any 1GP package (of which unmanaged packages are a flavour). There are so many obstacles when using 1GP that 2GP (so unlocked packages, as the natural replacement here) removes. It is also easier to automate release management with 2GP.

@PhilW Agree. I haven't used a 1GP in a quite a while, and I'd be happy to never have to look back.
